# Best practices when R package needs to create a configuration file

Tags: r, packaging

I am creating a package in R that exports a function which creates a configuration file.

When running `devtools::check()` I am getting the `NOTE` below:

```
❯ checking for non-standard things in the check directory ... NOTE
  Found the following files/directories:
    ‘conf_file.cfg’
```

I've verified that it refers to files that supposed not be there.

So, I looked to some packages that creates `configuration files` as [lintr](https://github.com/r-lib/lintr). The function `lintr::use_lintr()` creates a `.lintr` file. See below the function copied from `lintr`'s GitHub page.

```
#' Create a minimal lintr config file as a starting point for customization
#'
#' @param path Path to project root, where a `.lintr` file should be created.
#' If the `.lintr` file already exists, an error will be thrown.
#' @param type What kind of configuration to create?
#'
#'  * `tidyverse` creates a minimal lintr config, based on the default linters ([linters_with_defaults()]).
#'    These are suitable for following [the tidyverse style guide](https://style.tidyverse.org/).
#'  * `full` creates a lintr config using all available linters via [linters_with_tags()].
#'
#' @return Path to the generated configuration, invisibly.
#'
#' @export
#' @seealso `vignette("lintr")` for detailed introduction to using and configuring lintr.
#' @examples
#' if (FALSE) {
#'   # use the default set of linters
#'   lintr::use_lintr()
#'   # or try all linters
#'   lintr::use_lintr(type = "full")
#'
#'   # then
#'   lintr::lint_dir()
#' }
use_lintr <- function(path = ".", type = c("tidyverse", "full")) {
  config_file <- normalizePath(file.path(path, getOption("lintr.linter_file")), mustWork = FALSE)
  if (file.exists(config_file)) {
    stop("Found an existing configuration file at '", config_file, "'.")
  }
  type <- match.arg(type)
  the_config <- switch(
    type,
    tidyverse = list(
      linters = 'linters_with_defaults() # see vignette("lintr")',
      encoding = '"UTF-8"'
    ),
    full = list(
      linters = 'all_linters(packages = "lintr") # see vignette("lintr")',
      encoding = '"UTF-8"',
      exclusions = 'list("renv", "packrat") # see ?lintr::exclude'
    )
  )
  write.dcf(the_config, config_file, width = Inf)
  invisible(config_file)
}
```

**Note** that `@examples` has an `if (FALSE)` statement. So, the example will not run during the `devtools::check()` command.

In my case, I tried to insert the filename in the `.Rbuildignore` file, but no success on that.

Well, I can use the `if (FALSE)` statement as well, but would it be the best/only solution to stop receiving the `NOTE`?

**UPDATE**

`.Rbuildignore`

```
^renv$
^renv\.lock$
^.*\.Rproj$
^\.Rproj\.user$
^conf.*$
```

Comment: The entries in `.Rbuildignore` are regex, is your pattern for the filename a good match? I suggest you add the contents of `.Rbuildignore`, perhaps we can help there.

Comment: In all of my packages, when I don't want the `@examples` side-effect, I use `\dontrun` in the examples section. That is, after `#' @examples`, I have `#' \dontrun{`, then all of the sample roxygen-covered code, and end it with `#' }` (to match the dontrun).

Comment: Bottom line, I don't know off-hand (atm) why the pattern is not matched in `.Rbuildignore`, but you can avoid the file-generation by telling R to not run/process the example code.

Comment: I've jus read about `.Rinstignore`. Should I use it instead?

Comment: I have no experience with `.Rinstignore`. BTW, what happens if you remove the `^` anchor from your `.Rbuildignore` lines (for the file, at least)? What about just one of `conf_file\.cfg` `.*\.cfg$`, or something along those lines?

Comment: @r2evans, thanks for your help. Your suggestion did not solve it. But, your comments drove me to what I consider the "best practice".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250765/discussion-between-paulo-marques-and-r2evans).

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not convinced it is the best way to do it, I will show the solution I found for the "best practices" on creating a configuration file.

Basically, splitting function in two makes sense for test purposes during the `devtools::check()` process. I would appreciate more comments on this.

Follow an small example:

```
#' @title create_file
#'
#' @description Creates a configuration file
#'
#' @param conf_file A full path for the setting_file
#' @examples
#' \dontshow{full_path_filename <- tempfile()}
#' create_file(full_path_filename)

create_file <- function(conf_file) {
  write("# This is an empty file", file = conf_file)
}


#' @title initialize
#'
#' @description Initializes the enviroment
#'
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{initialize()}
#' @export

initialize <- function() {
  project_path <- getwd()
  configuration_file <- file.path(project_path, "conf_file.cfg")
  create_file(conf_file = configuration_file)
}
```

So, the idea is to have an `exported` function that works as an orchestrator, and which will not be tested (`\dontrun`) - Thanks [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans).

The function that effectively creates the file uses `\dontshow` to create a tempfile. The `\dontshow` will enclose code that is invisible on help pages, but that will run during tests.